# Make React Native Multiline Text Input that Hides Keyboard On Drag and Doesn't Hide Cursor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

This `<ScrollView>` with ` solution hides the keyboard well if you drag down, but your text hides under the cursor:

```
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        enabled
        behavior='height'
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}
      >
        <ScrollView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
          keyboardDismissMode={
            Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'interactive' : 'on-drag'
          }
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        >
          <Input
            multiline
            scrollEnabled={false}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This `<View>` approach with `<Input scrollEnabled={true}>` works well with the input not getting covered, but dismissing the keyboard requires tapping outside of the input.

```
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Input
            multiline
            scrollEnabled={true}
          />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I've also tried `KeyboardAwareScrollView` but it's very glitchy - it moves the text input very awkwardly and is delayed.

Is there anyone who's been able to make a multiline text input that:

1. Hides on drag
2. Is easily editable/scrollable
   ?

A perfectly working example of this is the iOS Notes app.